# How to match multiple ranges of column values to a row, and record in another location, using VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am volunteering with an NGO, helping to create a SQL database for their weekly client attendance data. Data currently sits in an Excel spreadsheet.

I want to manipulate said spreadsheet to avoid having them change their process.

***About this spreadsheet:***
Each row represents a different client, while a range of 3 columns holds the following info (time in, time out, and units) for 5 days of the week. Right above the time in - units block, is the date of service that set of info pertains to (the dates are merged across that range normally, but I had to un-merge that).  A screenshot is below for reference

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

***What I need done:***
I need to record each instance of every client's attendance on a separate row (in a different location - can be on the same sheet), matching the corresponding date of service, time in, time out, and units, to the name.

***What I have tried:*** 
I tried doing a `For... Next` loop with 3 counters for the 3 different ranges of info I need to look up, and declared the counters as ranges. I'm not sure if `While... Wend` is more appropriate here.

I also tried going the array way, but that's not coming together in my VBA.

I was also wondering if there is a datetime datatype that can be applied to Excel to eliminate having to match that additional range of values to the rest.

Side note: The greyed out cells on the sheet means the client isn't scheduled to attend on that day. So I need to include an If statement to skip cells that are blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do what you require, enough to get you started I hope - please note I have two sheets, Sheet1 (where data is stored) and Sheet2 (where data is moved to)

I have put the loops in where r = current row on sheet1, c = current column and then x is the counter for sheet2

r loop starts on row 3 and only goes to 5 for an example but you can find the last row and change the 5, or use a lastRow variable e.g. `lastRow = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row`

This all assumes that the data is always in exactly the format shown in your screenshot. You can rearrange the output easily enough within the innermost IF and END IF chunk

```
Sub shift_me()

Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim x As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

x = 1

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For r = 3 To 5
        For c = 3 To 15 Step 3
            If Not .Cells(r, c).Value2 = "" And Not .Cells(r, c).Value2 = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(x, 1).Value2 = .Cells(r, 1).Value2
                ws.Cells(x, 2).Value2 = .Cells(r, 2).Value2
                ws.Cells(x, 3).Value2 = .Cells(r, c).Value2
                ws.Cells(x, 4).Value2 = .Cells(r, c + 1).Value2
                ws.Cells(x, 5).Value2 = .Cells(r, c + 2).Value2
                ws.Cells(x, 6).Value2 = .Cells(1, c).Value2
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is Super useful! I would like to continue storing the values for subsequent weeks on "Sheet2". Can you please direct where I can instruct the code to begin storing the values on the next empty row?

Comment: So imagine "Sheet2" was already occupied up to, say, row 40... you could then use similar to what I mentioned above, replace `x = 1` with: `x = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row + 1` - this would give you x = 41. Now when you run the macro x is the next blank row in Sheet2 and it'll begin looping through and extracting from "Sheet1" again (or whichever sheet you tell it!)